# Repeating WinKey on Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, drivers, keyboard, dock

I installed Windows 10 on my Leonovo Miix 3 (with keyboard dock). Most things wok fine. One thing is driving me up the wall, I've tried all sorts.

When you press and hold the WinKey down, it treats it as a repeat key press like it would do with a regular key, e.g. holding 'g' produces 'gggggggggggggggg' ... this is causing problems because it means I have to do my WinKey combinations (i.e. snapping left/right) before the start bar pops up

There are only Windows drivers for Windows 8.1 for this device, and even those do not have specific keyboard/dock drivers. Only software utilities which I have tried!

Any ideas?

Comment: I've heard that Synaptics drivers can mess with other things. Does your laptop have a Synaptics touchpad?

Comment: @MC10 Yes it does - I will try uninstall it

Comment: @MC10 I uninstalled the Synaptics touchpad driver, and whilst I have lost the advanced features (e.g. gestures, etc) which I don't use anyway, my issues with the WinKey has disappeared. I'd like to give you the bounty but I think you need to submit this solution as an answer rather than a comment. Once you have I will accept it! Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Synaptics drivers have been causing problems with Windows 10. Check if your laptop uses a Synaptics touchpad. If it does, uninstall the drivers.

As OP mentioned in the comments, you will lose touchpad features such as gestures. Hopefully they release an update for Windows 10 that will fix this, but for now uninstalling will fix the Windows key issue.

In addition, you need to un-dock and re-dock for Windows 10 to automatically install the "HID-compliant mouse" driver. Once you have done this, follow the guide [here](http://www.thewindowsclub.com/stop-windows-7-from-installing-drivers-automatically), otherwise some Synaptics drivers are automatically installed at some point.